# while loop not functioning correctly

Tags: python

Essentially I need this code I've written in JES to keep asking the user regardless of how many times and what combination (which is clearly an issue at the moment) and only exit if the number entered is between 0 and 9. At the moment if I enter -3 and then enter 50 it exits. I'm not sure whether I'm close or very far off.

Cheers.

```
def main()
userInput = requestInteger("Enter a number between 0 and 9...")
  while userInput < int(0) :
    printNow("Error! Inputs must be between 0 and 9. Please re-enter...")
    userInput = requestInteger("Enter a number between 0 and 9...")
  while userInput > 9:
    printNow("Error! Inputs must be between 0 and 9. Please re-enter...")
    userInput = requestInteger("Enter a number between 0 and 9...")
  print "Thanks, you have entered: ",userInput,
```

Comment: Your code is missing a `:` after the function name. Please make sure you paste your original code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've written is working exactly as expected... if you want to keep asking the user for input, you'll want to use a `while True` and `break` out of it when correct input is given:

```
while True:
    user_input = requestInteger("Enter a number between 0 and 9...")

    if not 0 <= user_input <= 9:
        printNow("Error! Input must be between 0 and 9. Please re-enter.")
    else:
        print "Thanks, you've entered: ", user_input
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

def main():

```
    user_input = int(raw_input("Enter a number between 0 and 9..."))

    while user_input not in range(0, 10):
            print("Error! Inputs must be between 0 and 9. Please re-enter...")
            user_input = int(raw_input("Enter a number between 0 and 9..."))
    else:
            print "Thanks, you have entered: ",user_input
```

main()